# How to switch back to the default locale in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, internationalization, next-router

In the Next.js app, I am using the next-i18next module for multi-language which is working fine. There are two languages one English and the other Arabic. Default is English.

For toggle, I am using the following code in `NavBar`.

```
import { useRouter} from "next/router"
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next'
import { useState } from 'react'

const NavBar = ({...props}) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { t } = useTranslation('navbar');
    const [language, setLanguage] = useState(router.locale)

const onChangeLanguage = (lang) => (e)=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(lang === 'ar') {
            router.push('ar')
        } else {
            
            router.push('/')
        }
    }

return (
  <>
    .....
    .....
    <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="en" onClick={onChangeLanguage('en')} value="en" defaultChecked = {language === 'en'} />
      <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineCheckbox1">English</label>
    </div>
    <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="ar" onClick={onChangeLanguage('ar')} value="ar" defaultChecked = {language === 'ar'} />
      <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineCheckbox2">Arabic</label>
    </div>
  </>
 )
}

export default NavBar;
```

So on the homepage i.e. `http://localhost:3000` when I check the Arabic language then it appends `/ar` after the URL and works good but it creates issues in the internal pages.

I have pages structure like

```
pages
   index.js
   settings 
      locations
        index.js
        add.js
        edit
          [...id].js
      products
        index.js
        add.js
        edit
           [...id].js
```

If I try to change the locale from `en` to `ar` on the internal page e.g. `http://localhost:3000/settings/products` then it redirects on the `http://localhost:3000/settings/ar` URL where it does not find any route so 404 appears.

In case if I have set `ar` locale from the homepage [`http://localhost:3000/ar`] then If I change the locale from `ar` to `en` on any internal page e.g. `http:localhost:3000/ar/settings/localtion/edit/<UUID>` then it does not set language as `en`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the current route but change the locale, you can use `router.asPath`  as the `url` then pass the `locale` in the options object (third argument) of [`router.push`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush).

```js
const onChangeLanguage = (lang) => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    router.push(router.asPath, undefined, { locale: lang })
}
```