# Next.js change locale for the current path that has query, using router

Tags: javascript, routes, next.js

I have a central place to change locale. I show a list of locales, and when the user clicks on any of them, I use `useRouter` to redirect the user to the **current** page, but in the selected locale:

```
var router = useRouter();

const changeLocale = (selectedLocal) => {
    router.push({
            pathname: router.pathname,
            query: router.query
        }, {
            pathname: router.pathname,
            query: router.query
        }, { locale });
}

<div onClick={() => changeLocale('fr')}>Fr</div>
```

It works very well for URLs that have no parameters. But when the URL has parameters, it gets duplicated. For example, I have a list of conferences and when the user clicks on a conference I'll take him to the conference page using this `Link`:

```
<Link
    href={{
        pathname: '/conference/[id]',
        query: { id: conf.id }
    }}
```

This takes the user to the `example.com/conference/5` for example. But when the user changes the locale on that page, I see the URL is changed to `example.com/conference/5?id=5`. As you can see, I have two duplicated id parameters here. And If I don't pass `query` to `router.push`, I see this error:

> Error: The provided `href` (/conference/[id]) value is missing query values (id) to be interpolated properly. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/href-interpolation-failed

How should I effectively reroute users and keep URL structure and parameters?

Comment: In your `changeLocale` function, try replacing the `router.push` call with `router.push(router.asPath, undefined, { locale: selectedLocal })`.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to switch back to the default locale in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778995/1870780)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
    const changeLocale = (locale) => {
        router.push({
            route: router.pathname,
            query: router.query
        }, router.asPath, { locale });
    }
```

Basically, I only changed the second parameter of the `router.push` method.

I took it from the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing):

> Note that to handle switching only the locale while preserving all routing information such as dynamic route query values or hidden href query values, you can provide the href parameter as an object:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter()
const { pathname, asPath, query } = router
// change just the locale and maintain all other route information including href's query
router.push({ pathname, query }, asPath, { locale: nextLocale })
```